# What is the proper way to build an XML text node from a string that contains unsafe entities?

Tags: apex, xml

I'm having a problem with the `Dom` class and its automatic escaping of strings added via `Dom.XmlNode.addTextNode(text)` and I'm not sure if I am doing it wrong and this is expected behavior or if this is a bug in the method.

Given a string: `Escaping special characters: < " ' > & these should all be escaped`

What I expected to happen was no automatic escaping of text by the `Dom` class, creating text nodes with unescaped entities and to need to use the `String.escapeXml()` method to sanitize the string myself.

However, due to the automatic escaping that is happening in the `.addTextNode()` method (or maybe in `.toXmlString()`), the result is double-escaped entities. (i.e. `&amp;amp;`)

My understanding is that there are 5 entities that should be escaped in XML. `< " ' > &` 
 Source: [List of XML and HTML character entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined%5Fentities%5Fin%5FXML)

Unfortunately, based on my testing it looks like the `.addTextNode()` method only escapes `<` and `&`. So, I cannot rely on the method to escape the proper characters on my behalf, and I cannot pre-escape the string as it will result in double-escaped entities.

Exec Anon:

```
String bookTitle = 'XML Escaping';
String bookSubject = 'Escaping special characters: < " \' > & these should all be escaped';
system.debug('Subject: ' + bookSubject);

// create the Document
Dom.Document xmlDoc = new Dom.Document();

// create the root node & one child node with two child nodes containing text
dom.XmlNode DocumentRoot = xmlDoc.createRootElement('DocumentRoot', 'someNS', '');
  dom.XmlNode BookInfo = DocumentRoot.addChildElement('BookInfo', null, null);
    BookInfo.addChildElement('Title', null, null).addTextNode(bookTitle);
    BookInfo.addChildElement('Subject', null, null).addTextNode(bookSubject);


// output the results
String xmlAsString = xmlDoc.toXmlString();
system.debug('&gt; : ' + xmlAsString.contains('&gt;'));
system.debug('&lt; : ' + xmlAsString.contains('&lt;'));
system.debug('&amp; : ' + xmlAsString.contains('&amp;'));
system.debug('&quot; : ' + xmlAsString.contains('&quot;'));
system.debug('&apos; : ' + xmlAsString.contains('&apos;'));

// for good measure
system.debug(xmlAsString);
```

Results:

```
Subject: Escaping special characters: < " ' > & these should all be escaped

&gt; : false
&lt; : true
&amp; : true
&quot; : false
&apos; : false

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DocumentRoot xmlns="someNS">
    <BookInfo>
        <Title>XML Escaping</Title>
        <Subject>Escaping special characters: &lt; " ' > &amp; these should all be escaped</Subject>
    </BookInfo>
</DocumentRoot>
```

1. Is this a bug?
2. Am I building a node containing text that may contain unsafe characters incorrectly?
3. Is there an alternative using the `Dom` classes?
   (I don't desire to build the XML output via strings by hand.)

**Update:**

In the end, this wasn't a problem with the entities in the XML structure but was actually a problem that stemmed from forgetting to UTF-8 encode the raw XML string when it was used in a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` payload and sent out as an HTTPRequest. Don't forget your encoding!

```
EncodingUtil.urlEncode(xmlAsString, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In element text the only requirement is to escape < and &, so i beleive the behaviour you're seeing is correct.

The [Character](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax) data section of the XML Spec says

"The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) must not appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they must be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings "&amp;" and "&lt;" respectively."

It goes on to explain the escaping > is optional, except for the end of a CDATA section, which is a sequence of ]]> if you add this to your test you can see that that is correctly escaped to ]]&gt; so everything appears to be behaving correctly.